# Cypher queries fails with Neo4jError: Unknown function 'apoc.convert.fromJsonMap' but apoc should be installed

Tags: neo4j, cypher, kubernetes-helm, neo4j-apoc

I deployed Neo4j in my AKS cluster using the standalone Helm chart.
It all gets deployed and my Node.js server connects to Neo4j correctly.

However queries throw the `Neo4jError: Unknown function 'apoc.convert.fromJsonMap'` error, so `apoc` is clearly missing.

I followed the procedure described here https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/kubernetes/configuration/#operations-installing-plugins and my Values are here below.

The only difference I find is that in the guide `apoc core` is actually enabled afterwards by upgrading the helm chart, while I'm installing it with the option enabled already.

Looking at https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/config/ I saw

> As of Neo4j v.5.0, APOC config settings are no longer supported in the neo4j.conf file. Please move all apoc.* settings to apoc.conf. It is also possible to set the config settings using environment variables.

so as neo4j-standalone  is using version 4.4.16 I moved the apoc configurations from apoc.config to neo4.config but still apoc procedures are not found by the queries.

Is there something I'm missing out to configure in order to enable apoc?
Thank you very much.

```
neo4j-db:
# neo4j-standalone:
  nameOverride: "neo4j"
  fullnameOverride: 'neo4j'
  neo4j:
   # Name of your cluster
    name: "fixit-neo4j" # this will be the label: app: value for the service selector
    password: "password"
    ##
    passwordFromSecret: ""
    passwordFromSecretLookup: false
    edition: "community"
    acceptLicenseAgreement: "yes"
    offlineMaintenanceModeEnabled: false 
    resources:
      cpu: "1000m"
      memory: "2Gi"

  volumes:
    data:

      mode: 'volumeClaimTemplate'
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: neo4j-sc-data
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 4Gi


    backups:
      mode: 'share' # share an existing volume (e.g. the data volume)
      share:
        name: 'logs'

    logs:

      mode: 'volumeClaimTemplate'
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: neo4j-sc-logs
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 4Gi


  services:
    # A ClusterIP service with the same name as the Helm Release name should be used for Neo4j Driver connections originating inside the
    # Kubernetes cluster.
    default:
      # Annotations for the K8s Service object
      annotations: { }

  # A LoadBalancer Service for external Neo4j driver applications and Neo4j Browser
    neo4j:
    ### this would create cluster-neo4j svc
      enabled: false
 # env:
 #   NEO4J_PLUGINS: '["graph-data-science"]'
  config:
     
    server.bolt.enabled : "true"
    server.bolt.tls_level: "REQUIRED"
    server.bolt.listen_address: "0.0.0.0:7687"
    dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.client_auth: "NONE"
    dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.enabled: "true"
    
    server.directories.plugins: "/var/lib/neo4j/labs" 
    dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted: "apoc.*"
    server.config.strict_validation.enabled: "false"
    dbms.security.procedures.allowlist: "gds.*,apoc.*"
  apoc_config:
    apoc.trigger.enabled: "true"
    apoc.jdbc.neo4j.url: "jdbc:foo:bar"
    apoc.import.file.enabled: "true"


  
  startupProbe:
    failureThreshold: 1000
    periodSeconds: 50

  ssl:
  # setting per "connector" matching neo4j config
    bolt:
      privateKey:
        secretName: tls-secret 
        subPath:  tls.key 
      publicCertificate:
        secretName: tls-secret 
        subPath:  tls.crt 
      trustedCerts:
        sources: [ ] 
      revokedCerts:
        sources: [ ]
```

Comment: How did you install APOC plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK after a bit of looking at quite a few issues on the same subject, I found that some solutions for this problem was to add `dbms.directories.plugins: "/var/lib/neo4j/labs"` and `dbms.config.strict_validation: "false"` in the `config` section which, as I understand it, mirrors these settings both for `server` and `dbms`. It indeed worked, but it's weird that in the official guide it's not mentioned. I mean, these mirrored settings make sense, tell both the `server` and the `dbms` where to look for plugins, but still it should be mentioned. I see so many post about this, which means the documentation is not clear enough. It's easy to take things for granted and in fact because this mirrored plugin location both for the `server` `AND` `dbms` need is just not stated anywhere in the docs, I as many others  thought that `dbms` was already configured with the same location as `server.directories.plugins: "/var/lib/neo4j/labs"` ( which the docs say to configure ) and haven't added it, but hey.. ain't nobody's perfect I guess. Hope they change the docs then for future devs' sake, but meanwhile this answer could be helpful.

So the correct configuration is

```
  env:
    NEO4J_PLUGINS: '["graph-data-science"]'
  config:
    server.bolt.enabled: 'true'
    server.bolt.tls_level: 'REQUIRED'
    server.bolt.listen_address: '0.0.0.0:7687'
    dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.client_auth: 'NONE'
    dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.enabled: 'true'

    ## apoc
    server.directories.plugins: '/var/lib/neo4j/labs'
    server.config.strict_validation.enabled: 'false'
    dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted: 'apoc.*'
    dbms.security.procedures.allowlist: 'gds.*,apoc.*'

    ### additional needed dbms config mirroring server config
    dbms.directories.plugins: "/var/lib/neo4j/labs"
    dbms.config.strict_validation: "false"

  apoc_config:
    apoc.trigger.enabled: "true"
    apoc.jdbc.neo4j.url: "jdbc:foo:bar"
    apoc.import.file.enabled: "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the docs are missing installing the APOC plugin. Change the following line to include APOC as well:

```
NEO4J_PLUGINS: '["graph-data-science", "apoc"]'
```

and you should be good

Comment: Hi Tomaz, thanks for answering, after a bit of looking in GitHub issues I found that ini the `config` section some suggestion at the same problem of mine was to add `dbms.directories.plugins: "/var/lib/neo4j/labs"` and `dbms.config.strict_validation: "false"` which I see it mirrors this settings for `server`. It actually worked, but it's weird that in the official guid it's not mentioned. I mean, these settings make sense, tell both the server and the dbms where to look for plugins, but still it should be mentioned. I see so many post about this, which means poor documentation.

Comment: also, as stated in the docs, `apoc` comes included and doesn't need additional installation as opposed to `gds`, it's just not stated anywhere in the docs that you should mirror the location for the dbms too. As a result, I thought it was already configured that way and haven't added it, but hey.. ain't nobody's perfect I guess.

Comment: Can you please post the solution here, even I don't know what's correct now

Comment: Hi Tomaz, there you have the correct setting for the config and apoc_config , if you need more info just ask. Cheers